# How to clean a specific index array?

Tags: php

I want to clean a specific index of array, in particular I've 3 index:

```
0: 
   Appointments
   Unavailables
1:
   Appointments
   Unavailables
2:
   Appointments
   Unavailables
```

Now I want maintain the first appointments as 0 index. So this is my code:

```
foreach($appointments as $key => value)
{ 
   if($key != 0)
   {
      unset($appointments[$key]['appointments']);    
   }
}
```

but `unset` delete also the key so the final result that I get is:

```
0: 
   Appointments
   Unavailables
1:
   Unavailables
2:
   Unavailables
```

I want maintain the `appointments` object, just I need to empty it's content. 
How I can achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of unsetting it just set it equal to an empty array:

`$appointments[$key]['appointments'] = []`

If it is an object as you state instead of an array, create a new one:

`$appointments[$key]['appointments'] = new MyAppointmentObject;`